# how to make tag supporting in input text of bootstrap material design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/liza_susan/cra13ygj/) here.but its showing error while give the input tags. i want the label to jumb upwards while clicking the input text and can add the tags in input text

html

```
<form>
                                    <div class="md-form form-width">

                                        <input type="text" id="form41"  class="form-control tags">
                                        <label for="form41" class="">Keywords/Tags (Type 5 to 20 items)  </label>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

js

```
<script>
        // Material Select Initialization
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mdb-select').material_select();


      $('.tags').tagsinput({
        allowDuplicates: true
    });
        $('.tags').on('itemAdded', function(item, tag) {
        $('.items').html('');
        var tags = $('.tags').tagsinput('items');
        $.each(tags, function(index, tag) {
            $('.items').append('<span>' + tag + '</span>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't have jquery included in your fiddle, maybe that's part of the problem ? https://jsfiddle.net/cra13ygj/1/

Comment: but when it is added the material design of input text gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the console error message I would say you need to import also jQuery:

> (index):69 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>   bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
>   jQuery

Comment: added jquery now but the bootstrap material design of input text is not working

Comment: You are missing to initialize it, $.material.init() anyway from what I see the problem is that the two plugin are not compatible

Comment: The init is in the getting started of bootstrap material design documentation http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#getting-started

Comment: Actually I do not see also the material.min.js, please read the documentation and add all the necessary assets.